# Is it possible to measure response time of an API in EKS with Istio

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, istio

I have an application running in EKS with istio service mesh, exposed using istio ingress and alb. Is there a tool to measure the amount of time (response time) taken by API request on each service? For instance, what time it reached ingress, then gateway and virtual service down to the pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Istio access logs can be enabled to see different details.  Below is [default logging](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/) format.

```
[%START_TIME%] \"%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%\" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %RESPONSE_CODE_DETAILS% %CONNECTION_TERMINATION_DETAILS%
\"%UPSTREAM_TRANSPORT_FAILURE_REASON%\" %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION% %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% \"%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%\" \"%REQ(USER-AGENT)%\" \"%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%\"
\"%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%\" \"%UPSTREAM_HOST%\" %UPSTREAM_CLUSTER% %UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS% %REQUESTED_SERVER_NAME% %ROUTE_NAME%\n
```

For istio [observability](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/observability/)  to [visualize service mesh](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/kiali/) please refer their documentation.

Comment: Thank you! This is incredibly helpful